# Can ring of shooting stars affect the same target more than once?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

Under the ball of lightning effect from ring of shooting stars it says:

> As a Bonus Action, you can move each Sphere up to 30 feet, but no farther than 120 feet away from you. When a creature other than you comes within 5 feet of a Sphere, the Sphere discharges lightning at that creature and disappears. That creature must make a DC 15 Dexterity saving throw.

Can the same target be affected by the ball of lightning more than once if I move it in and out 5 feet from the enemy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just as you said in your question:

> When a creature other than you comes within 5 feet of a Sphere, the Sphere discharges lightning at that creature **and disappears**.

As soon as the ball affects a creature, it's gone. So it doesn't really matter whether it would affect a creature multiple times if you moved it back and forth, because the first time it affects a creature is the last time it will affect anything.

Comment: Oh that's embarrassing over read that Thanks